# Is the Point Estimate for variance of Bernoulli Unbiased?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from the Bernoulli family with parameter $p$. Let $\sigma^2$ be the variance of $X_1$. Consider the point estimate for $\sigma^2$ given by $\overline{X}(1-\overline{X})$. Is it unbiased?

Since $\overline{X}(1-\overline{X}) = \overline{X}-(\overline{X})^2$, we have $\mathbb{E}(\overline{X}(1-\overline{X})) = \mathbb{E}(\overline{X}-(\overline{X})^2)= \mathbb{E}\overline{X}-\mathbb{E}(\overline{X})^2$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}\overline{X}=\mu$ and $\mathbb{E}(\overline{X})^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$.

Putting them in $\mathbb{E}\overline{X}-\mathbb{E}(\overline{X})^2$ we find that it equals to $\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}-\mu^2$ which is not equal to $\sigma^2$ and thus it is not unbiased. Is this correct?

Comment: Please: Don't write $\overline{X^2}$ if you mean ${\overline X}^2. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks! edited,

Comment: But now you have an ambiguity: Does $\operatorname E\left(\overline X\right)^2$ mean $\operatorname E\left( \overline X^2\right)$ or does it mean $\left( \operatorname E (X) \right)^2 \text{ ?}$ Usually that notation refers to the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$We have $\mu = p$ and $\sigma^2 = p(1-p) = \mu(1-\mu) = \mu-\mu^2.$

So
\begin{align}
\e\big( \overline X(1-\overline X) \big) = \e\left(\overline X\right) - \e\left( \overline X ^2 \right) & = \mu - \left( \mu^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) \\[10pt]
& = (\mu-\mu^2) - \frac{\sigma^2} n \\[10pt]
& = \sigma^2 - \frac{\sigma^2} n = \frac{n-1} n \sigma^2.
\end{align}
So this estimator is biased. If I'm not mistaken, it has a slightly smaller mean squared error than does the best unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{E}(\overline{X}(1-\overline{X})) = \mathbb{E}(\overline{X}-(\overline{X})^2)= \mathbb{E}[\overline{X}]-\mathbb{E}[(\overline{X})^2] =p-\mathbb{E}[(\overline{X})^2] < p-(\mathbb{E}\overline{X})^2 = p-p^2$$ thanks to Jensen's Inequality. Thus it is biased.